# How to build an executable with Cmake where all the dependence are contained in the project DIR?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, dlib

I am on a project using OpenCV and Dlib and I would like the project to be cross platform and self-contained. So I can just just copy the project Dir to another platform and be able to get the exe by ruing cmake .

The DIR:

```
project/   
          opencv-3.2.0
         |
          dlib-19.2
         |
          include
         |
          source
```

---

Where the "opencv-3.2.0" and "dlib-19.2" contains the respective source code for the library downloaded from the official site. The "include" and "source" contained my .h and .cpp respectively.

---

This is the CMakeLists.txt thit I hanve come up with so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(visionBean)


set (OPENCV_VERSION_DIR_NAME ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/opencv-3.2.0)
set (DLIB_VERSION_DIR_NAME ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dlib-19.2)


#setup opencv

add_subdirectory(${OPENCV_VERSION_DIR_NAME})
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

#setup dlib
add_subdirectory(${DLIB_VERSION_DIR_NAME})
include_directories( ${DLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

 #files for main project
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source)

file(GLOB ${PROJECT_NAME}_INC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE ${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} source/demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_LINKER ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${DLIB_LIBS})
```

If some one has done this before can you show me how this can be done or point me in the right direction please? Thank you

---

**Edit**
The Fist camke error I ran into is:

CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: opencv_xxx

Comment: Can you please give a specific problem or error message? Otherwise this is more something for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Generally speaking why haven't you used `find_package()`?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will add it into edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this gonna work. you're adding a complete project as subdirectory.

opencv is itself a CMake project, since it's top level CMakeList.txt has a `project` command, it's not merely a subdirectory.

You can modify the opencv CMakeLists.txt, make it into a mere subdirectory, but I don't recommand that, just write a script(*.sh for linux and *.bat for windows) to call cmake for each project.